A class for students who want to get better at a subject, aside from their public education
A class for students who want to get better at a subject, aside from their public education.

It is often scheduled in the evening, but not necessarily, and young students are more likely to be here than adults => it rules out an evening class.
The students are neither necessarily slow, nor necessarily in high school => it rules out a remedial class.
The number of students enrolled ranges from 1 to 50 or even more => it rules out a tutoring class.
An extra class is ambiguous.
A cram class sounds closest in meaning, but this class might not prepare students for entrance exams, which cram schools are typically established to help students prepare for in Japan or Korea => so maybe not this one as well?

I've been spending the last two hours finding the best word for this and it's so frustrating.

remedial is not used in the US for slow students.  I already told you this: https://www.insidehighered.com/views/2023/01/09/students-should-refuse-remedial-placements-opinion#:~:text=Essentially%2C%20remedial%20courses%20are%20review,to%20be%20successful%20in%20college.

https://www.canr.msu.edu/news/understanding_remedial_classes_in_college But what does aside from public education even mean? Do you mean for grade 1 through 12?

You said remedial classes are for high school students, these classes are for all people actually. But yes, they're mostly for students from grade 1 to 12, so let's focus on that.

The reason why still added the "slow students" part was because two different dictionaries that I looked the word up say so. There's contradictory information here so I added it just in case.

You spent two hours unsuccessfully trying to find "the best word". Doesn't this suggest that even if you did find what looks like "le mot juste", it would be fairly pointless to use it, since your readers / audience would be unlikely to understand it anyway. I advise you to concentrate on finding a succinct, easily-understood, unambiguous way of referring to what you wish to name, to be sure you're actually communicating (as opposed to showing off your domain-specific specialist knowledge that may only be meaningful to some people in the teaching profession).

As far as I know, there is nothing in the UK that satisfies all these criteria, so there is no word for it. I think 'extra classes in [subject]' is your best bet.

Dictionaries don't cut this kind of thing. You have to look  up usage in context by educational institutions: Remedial + classes + college Those links I gave you show how remediation is used in education in the US.

In my first link: Essentially, remedial courses are review courses. They re-expose students to content they have not yet mastered or have forgotten to build the foundational knowledge and skills they need to be successful in college.

I think Lambie's "remedial is not for slow students" thing is only half the story. "For slow students" is definitely part of the connotation of remedial classes, but it isn't necessarily true (somebody might need a remedial class if e.g. they are very smart but their previous school didn't teach that subject, or they are going back to school as an adult and haven't used that skill in years.) But many people would consider being told to take a remedial class as a bit of an insult--I wouldn't call a course I was offering "remedial" to try and attract students.

(e.g. most english-for-nonnative-speakers classes in the American education system are called something like "ELL" or "English speech and composition for nonnative speakers" and not "remedial English", because remedial has that negative connotation)

Perhaps a word that means "in addition to", such as supplementary classes. You could explain the content of those classes first time round, then the short label would suffice after that.

I don't think there is one word for this. It would be named after other factors. If it is taken in the evening, it might be called a "night class". If it's taught by the local department of parks and recreation (a common thing in the US), then someone might say they "took a class in X at the rec center" or "through the parks department". Or it might just be called "a class in X" or "an X class". Just because it's for adults and not at a university doesn't mean it wouldn't be called a class like any other. "I took a painting class." "Oh, where did you take it?" "At the rec center".

will something centered around "optional", or "facultative" work? Extracurricular might have an issue because it is often used for something completely outside the usual subjects. A karate class (or a piano class in a non-music school) is extracurricural. But if you have 3 math classes per week and you organize a fourth one for students who want to learn more than what is mandatory (and maybe take part in a math competition), that is something which is part of the subjects the others learn, it's just extra on top, and I guess this is what you mean in the question

Enrichment class?

@Kaia remedial classes are not directed at non-natives at al.  They are make-up classes. facultative is not used,that's for sure. facultatif is optional.

One useful word for an activity that falls outside of the standard school instruction is extracurricular, since it literally means just that, "outside of the curriculum." You could say:

I'm starting an extracurricular English class for students who want to increase their skills.

This might be best for your specific situation, especially if the topic is one that is also covered in school. Often for these sorts of classes, they're offered because they cover a topic that's not covered in school. In these cases it's often enough just to name the subject and use the word "class," since it's understood that it's outside of school hours:

"I'm late for karate class."
"I can't, I have Hebrew class."


(By the way, to address a few details:

"Remedial" classes are not limited to high school; it could be for any time that the student needs a "remedy." But it's often replaced with other terms to avoid shame or stigma, like "catch-up classes."
You're right to think that there might be a size limit on "tutoring." Many dictionaries say things like "especially individually." But I don't think it's strictly limited to 1-on-1; a dozen or so could be tutored at once. It has two simultaneous senses: it could emphasize individual instruction (like in older times in which a young aristocrat would have "a tutor" as their sole source of instruction), or it could emphasize the fact that it supports and is outside of regular instruction. So if your "supplemental" class was small enough you could call it "tutoring," but it has an expectation that each student gets direct attention.


These classes often teach students the most common subjects. Extracurricular classes to me sound like something organized by schools, and, like what you said, covering topics outside the main curricula. A long version to further explain it like yours or Tim's can totally deliver the meaning, but I want a word for daily use, so a shorter word/phrase is more ideal.

I think this fits the desired criteria well (at least in British English). @AnIELTSLearner Anything not in the school's curriculum is extracurricular, it might be completely unaffiliated with any school so I don't agree with it sounding like the opposite. From dictionary.cambridge.org  "An extracurricular activity or subject is not part of the usual school or college course"

@AnIELTSLearner Yes, although the dictionary entry says "connected with school," it's often used for things that aren't. A college application might ask what "extracurricular activities" you've participated in. We use the term around our house for things like harp lessons, taekwondo, and community theater, as in "You're too busy with all these extracurricular activities." They differ from hobbies or pastimes like hiking or reading by being organized and regularly scheduled, but that's about it.

I suggest "supplemental" class, which in and of itself carries little to no negative connotation.
However, the word has been co-opted somewhat, at least here in Canada, to refer to courses that appear more remedial or perhaps preventative, rather than 'extra'. See "SL" (Supplemental Learning) for examples of this.

I don't agree with 'extracurricular', as this means a subject or class that is not on the school curriculum, so it would be wrong to describe extra classes of a subject that is studied in school time.
At both of the UK schools my kids currently attend, extra sessions or classes to help kids prepare for exams are called 'booster sessions'.

Interesting. Are these classes provided by schools or by other individuals who charge students for tuition fees?

@AnIELTSLearner the booster classes I spoke about from personal experience are provided by the school, which is an ordinary state school. I've removed the term 'enrichment' from my answer, this an American term and I now understand it to mean extracurricular.

How about "English Language Coaching in an informal classroom setting"?

I mean to use it frequently in daily conversation because this kind of class is super common in my country, so your suggestion is a bit long.

I guess it's true that this kind of class doesn't exist in the West, so using a short phrase with further explanation is unvoidable.

@AnIELTSLearner I think this kind of class probably does exist in the US, it just doesn't have a special name. It's just a "class". I've taught an "ear training class" outside of school.

@AnIELTSLearner I capitalized the short phrase, Engish Language Coaching.  BTW, you shouldn't expect us to read your mind. How do we know how you plan to use it? Could be you planned to offer such a course and needed a phrase for a poster you intended to place on a bulletin board in a lobby somewhere.

@TimR Don't get me wrong; it's not a complaint. I just tried to add the information that my question lacked and explained it further. I should have included that in the first place.

@AnIELTSLearner if you feel like sharing, what is your country and what is the word for this type of class? I'm still not exactly sure what kind of class we're talking about and I'd like to google it to figure out more

You can say you are enrolled in a/an (English) language course

I really needed to improve my Spanish speaking and listening skills, so I went to this language school twice a week for a year. My Spanish teacher was great– really knowledgeable–and my fellow classmates were at a good level, so I had plenty of speaking practice, too.

Substitute the word "language" with  any subject or hobby that is taught outside of school, e.g. a photography course

Could you expand more on why "course" is better than "class" here?

Who said it was better? You can have a language/photography class and you can say you are having "a language class" but if you enrol in a  course, it suggests that it begins and ends at a specified date.

I'll add another: recitation, taken from Georgia Tech's recitation faq:

Recitation is typically a smaller subset of a larger lecture course, commonly led by teaching assistants, designed to provide time for application of conceptual knowledge and extension of instruction that occurs in lecture through problem-solving or discussion.


What would you call a class that is neither an evening class./ nor a remedial class./ nor a tutoring class./nor an extra class/ nor a cram class
Are these names suitable for defining the function of your institute ?

A short term course
Short term skill development courses
Career oriented courses
Job oriented courses
Summer courses for adult and college students
Fun, Hobby & Leisure Classes
Coaching centres

The various courses can have individual names like:

Personal Finance Class
Design or Art Class
Business/Business Management
Speech or Communication Skills Classes
Journalism or Writing Courses
Computer Science Class/Web Design/Cybersecurity

